# ssh -Y using Cygwin/X without needing xterm

Tags: linux, cygwin

I manage a large farm of Linux servers/desktops from a Windows desktop machine and would like to reduce the complexity of this task by not having to use xterm for X Forwarding. This is my setup:

- I am using the excellent [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) for managing my ssh connections. I setup each tab by entering the following into the "Shell:" field in settings: `C:\cygwin\bin\ssh.exe user@server1`
- When I want to run a graphical application from a Linux box I do the following:

  - run `startxwin &` from my local cygwin bash
  - Right click on the X icon and start "xterm"
  - run `ssh -Y user@server1` in xterm
  - Then I can start xeyes or whatever from the Linux box

What I would like to do is not have the faff of having to open up xterm every time I want to run a graphical application on Cygwin/X. Ideally  my "tabbed" connections in ConsoleZ would just allow this by using `C:\cygwin\bin\ssh.exe -Y user@server1` in the "Shell:" field. If I do try this all I get is "Error: Can't open display:".

Any suggestions as to how I can make my life easier would be gratefully recieved (I can't use a Linux or Mac desktop machine even if I wanted to).

Comment: Why can't you use a Linux or Mac desktop? It's extraordinarily painful to try to manage Linux systems from a Windows desktop, as you've already discovered. The gain in efficiency is just too great to let this state of affairs stand for long.

Comment: It's a work thing (Outlook, MS Office, etc...). Also, ConsoleZ works really well for me. I have shortcuts to all of my servers and I even have a colour scheme. It's really not that bad. Now I could run everything in Virtual Box which is what a lot of people do but I have multiple monitors and other stuff going on in Windows and I like to mix and match. Having everything sandboxed in a VM window is more painful than having a few xterms open. It's still not perfect though.